# Keep inventory not working in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As I said in the title, keep inventory is not working. I have cheats on and no mods and I know for sure it is on.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @aphid That's about how to turn keep inventory on, not how to troubleshoot it if it doesn't work.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 See https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15259/duplicate-questions-relating-to-minecraft-keepinventory?noredirect=1#comment46242_15259. There's too many minor variations. The problem is often a simple mis-spelling of a command. I would like to have one proper resource on how to do it, not 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to determine the cause of your problem without further info so make sure this is what you are typing

```
/gamerule keepInventory true
```

A common mistake is to forget to add **/gamerule** and instead just type **/keepInventory**,  but this is classified as a gamerule. You must also remember to add a capital **I** for **keepInventory**

Make sure to include **true** at the end, this will activate the rule.  Just swap false in place of true to turn the rule off.

If it's still not working, try restarting your Minecraft.

Comment: Oh thanks I forgot to capitalize the I I'm so stupid .

Comment: ah, no worries glad to help (-: